# Installing Nvidia drivers in Ubuntu 18.04, I am getting "nvidia: command not found" but I have installed everything needed

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia

I am getting this error:
    nvidia -smi
    nvidia: command not found
[Installation steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmIj7.png)

After running the installation of Nvidia-440 drivers using ppa, the installation is a success but I can't run smi. Also, the graphics card is defaulted to Intel in the settings. I have searched everywhere for a possible answer and need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`smi` is not a command; the command you're looking for is `nvidia-smi`.

Comment: My mistake, but I forgot that there's actually a different problem. 

NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
& I have tried manual installing like other answers had suggested, and nothing is working.

Comment: You should post another question then.